# Nonlinear principal component analysis MATLAB code

Tags: multivariate-analysis, pca, matlab

I'm working on multivariate process monitoring using NLPCA method.
I need MATLAB code to implement this method.

Answer (score 3):

See [Matthias Scholz's site](http://www.nlpca.org) for the [MATLAB code](http://www.nlpca.org/matlab.html) (the homepage includes references).